# Can I remove or edit an include() from a function with a filter?

Tags: php, plugin-development, filters

I need to edit the output of a plugin and the part I need to change is actually a html file that is brought in using include(name-of-file.html).

The function has a filter, but I am just now beginning to understand how filters work, and cannot seem to figure out how to change that path.

Basically, I want to change the path to point to /my-theme/name-of-file.html instead, and I want to use a filter so whenever I need to update the plugin I don't need to remember to, or have to, edit the file again.

At any rate, this is the filter

`add_filter('eventon_eventCard_evotx', array($this, 'frontend_box'), 10, 2);`

and the function is

```
`function frontend_box($object, $helpers){
.....stuff that stays....
  include(name-of-file);
.....more stuff that stays.....
}`
```

I would appreciate any help you guys could offer or point me towards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not (easily) possible to interfere with PHP `include`.

What you can do in general is:

1. Fork a function (create your own copy under different name)
2. `remove_filter()` the original function
3. `add_filter()` of your function in its place

However that can get impractical very fast.

If the file being loaded makes sense to be customizable the first thing I would do is suggest to plugin developers to make it *easily* so, introducing a specific filter for it or otherwise.

Comment: ok,,looks like removing and re-adding will be the way to go then. This wouldn't be a file that most users of the plugin would want to edit much.